# Remove scaling in quiver plot (Octave)

Tags: plot, octave

I'm want to plot electric field of two point charges with `Octave`. I have managed to do that with `quiver()` function. But since I am more interested in the direction of the field than actual size I want to scale all arrows of the quiver plot to the same size and keep only their direction.

My question is how to scale arrows on the `quiver()` plot to same length? I found this topic in [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Quiver-group.html) but don't know how to use it.

Here is my code responsible for plotting:

```
h = quiver(xx, yy, Ex, Ey);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to scale arrows to same size with definition of unit vector. I divided each component of an arrow, x and y (in my case `Ex` and `Ey`) with length of an arrow which is defined as sqrt(x^2 + y^2).

Here is the code:

```
Exx = ((Ex)./(Ex.^2 + Ey.^2).^0.5);
Eyy = ((Ey)./(Ex.^2 + Ey.^2).^0.5);
```